# How to extract a sub text from a column and few places after that sub text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 columns `Employee Name` and `Employee History`. Employee History has a long text.
How can I find the text "Employment Start Date:" and the date that follows it and store it in a separate column for each row in the data frame. 
Like below

Col 1: `Employee Name`:

```
coopertire.com
```

Col 2 `Employee History`:

```
'Domain Name: COOPERTIRE.COM', '\n   Registry Domain ID: 3062569_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN', '\n   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com', '\n   Registrar URL: http://www.cscglobal.com/global/web/csc/digital-brand-services.html', '\n   Updated Date: 2020-02-16T06:24:09Z', '\n   Creation Date: 1997-02-19T05:00:00Z', '\n   Registry Expiry Date: 2022-02-20T05:00:00Z', '\n   Registrar: CSC Corporate Domains, Inc.', '\n   Registrar IANA ID: 299' 2/19/1997
```

I want to get from the above text

Col 3 `Creation Date`:

```
1997-02-19
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the given `regex` pattern:

```
df['Creation Date'] = df['Employee History'].str.extract(
    r"(?i)\bCreation Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")
```

---

```
# print(df)

    Employee Name                                   Employee History Creation Date
0  coopertire.com  ' Domain Name: COOPERTIRE.COM', '\n Registry D...    1997-02-19
```

You can test the regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/0Exr8N/1).

Comment: I tried, tested many such instances on your regex link it works well.

Comment: When I use it on a data frame with 100 rows all the values in the new columns says "NaN", dont understand what is wrong ..... hmm !!

Comment: You need to show the sample of dataframe, its really hard from your question to determine how your dataframe looks like.

Comment: Below is the link to my Jupyter Notebook which has the data frame in it https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmzbYEOby2Vqev4CO5_fk7wjeo0?e=1yi4Sl

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmzbYEOby2Vqev4CO5_fk7wjeo0?e=1yi4Sl

Comment: @jepaulabi The  creation date part in `Employee History` is not visible in the notebook you sent me.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmzbYEOby2Vqev4CO5_fk7wjeo0?e=GTWGFf       I uploaded the notebook again it should be visible now. I increased the column width. Some columns have Creation Date some don't the column name is "text".        Please check now

Comment: Sure @jepaulabi

Comment: @jepaulabi Its working correctly at my side, Whats your pandas version? Can you try `.str.extract(r"(?i)\bCreation Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})", expand=False)`?

Comment: I am using Python 3 I tried the expand=False still "NaN" :-( wonder what is wrong

Comment: I mean panads version.

Comment: 0.24.2 is the Pandas Version

Comment: Can you try .`str.findall(r"(?i)\bCreation Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})").str[0]`

Comment: Nops sorry same NaN again :-(

Comment: Try using this regex `r"\bCreation\s*Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"`. Let me know the result.

Comment: tried all the below, none seem to have worked .................. new['Creationdate']=new['text'].str.extract(r"(?i)\bCreation Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})", expand=False)
new['Creationdatenew']=new['text'].str.findall(r"(?i)\bCreation Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})").str[0]
new['try1']=new['text'].str.findall(r"\bCreation\s*Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")
new['try2']=new['text'].str.extract(r"\bCreation\s*Date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")

Comment: @anky got any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: @anky appreciate your thoughts please